# check status of RabbitMQ, whether message is published?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq, resque, bunny

I have one resque job which is run at some event which finally publishes the message to RabbitMQ's exchange, how can I check in bunny(Rabbit MQ ruby client) that whether the message has been successfully published?

Using Acknowledgment or any way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the `publish` you are not sure that the message is published on the queue.

If you want to be sure you have to use you have to use `publish confirm` or `tx transaction`.

Read this post http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/

Note: By default the clients don't have any HA policy, you have to implement it. See the section `Streaming Lightweight Publisher Confirms`:

```
private volatile SortedSet<Long> unconfirmedSet =

    Collections.synchronizedSortedSet(new TreeSet());

...

ch.setConfirmListener(new ConfirmListener() {
    public void handleAck(long seqNo, boolean multiple) {
        if (multiple) {
            unconfirmedSet.headSet(seqNo+1).clear();
        } else {
            unconfirmedSet.remove(seqNo);
        }
    }
    public void handleNack(long seqNo, boolean multiple) {
        // handle the lost messages somehow
    }
});
```

Note2: the message is never "put" inside an exchange, but always inside a queue.

Answer (score 0):

Once the `publish` method returns, the message has published to the queue.  There is no deferred action to publishing a message.

Comment: When you call `publish` method, it put it into the exchange, my question is what if rabbit MQ server is down and my resque job is not able to publish, how to republish/retry? see this section **How Message Acknowledgements Relate to Transactions and Publisher Confirms** of link http://rubybunny.info/articles/queues.html#message_acknowledgements, It says what if S1 is down, This is what i am looking solution for.